# Vagrant server content won't show in web browser on windows

Tags: windows, vagrant

I am trying to use vagrant on Windows system. I already gone through the step of add vagrant box, init it and vagrant up. And I also use PuttyGen and Putty to ssh into the VM as introduced here: http://blog.osteel.me/posts/2015/01/25/how-to-use-vagrant-on-windows.html

Now after installing all necessary packages, I try to run this code on the VM:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
 return 'SUCESSFULLY running flask inside centos68 via apache!\n\n'

if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

And I also go into my Vagrantfile on local machine and uncomment # config.vm.network “private_network”, ip: “192.168.33.10” by removing the # sign and save it. And it shows running on http://0.0.0:5000/

But when I type in the IP address and port number on browser, it shows:
The site can't be reached. It seems as if VM cannot communicate with local machine.

This kind of problem never occurred in Mac OS, I am wondering if it is because of Putty. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, a typo, it should be 'windows browser' instead of 'windows server' in the tile

Comment: And every time I modify the Vagrantfile on local machine, it will automatically add a file name: Vagrantfile~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I used Git Bash instead of Putty for the installation and everything works fine.